# C++ Unresolved external symbol - library problem?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors

Sorry if the question is dumb, I'm still a noobie.
I've got a header and a .lib file. I've included the header and set up the library file in the linker additional libraries directory, however I keep getting unresolved external symbol error over the functions defined in the header (which should be included in the library).
On the top of the header the following is written:

```
#pragma once

// To use the framework define _WINDOWS in project's settings!
#if defined(_WINDOWS)
    #if defined(FRAMEWORK_PROJECT)
        #define FRAMEWORK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define FRAMEWORK_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define FRAMEWORK_API 
#endif
```

Where would I need to define _WINDOWS variable, and what to? (Visual Studio) or is the problem something different entirely?

Comment: You specify the directory of the library among the "Additional Libraries" directories, then you also specify the library itself among the inputs for the linker.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that part in the question but it's also specified under the linker input tab

Comment: And `_WINDOWS` goes in the "Preprocessor" section of the "C/C++" project options.

Comment: you put the header in the same directory as you main.cpp ? Else you'll also need to add the path to include directories.

Comment: Thank you molbdnilo, the project compiled after setting _WINDOWS variable, however now I get an error that a dll object can't be found even though it is in the folder specified in the additional libraries directory next to my .lib file. Do I need to specify path to it somewhere else?

Comment: You need the DLL accessible at runtime, possibly in your working directory. The DLL search path is unrelated to that project setting.

Comment: The dll is added to the working directory and is visible on the project tree, is there a particular reason why it might not be found by visual studio?

Comment: Nevermind, the dll files were in the project folder but the compiled program was in a subfolder, once I copied the dll files right next to the executable it worked. Thank you so much @molbdnilo !